# How to iterate through an internationalised JSON array using i18next and Angular

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a series of json internationalization files with basic strings, arrays of strings and arrays of json objects, and I've been trying to display in angular them using various i18n libraries.
The en_GB file is below

```
{
  "key": "value en_GB",
    "headings": ["header1 en_GB", "header2 en_GB", "header3 en_GB"],
    "objects": [
        {"title": "title1 en_GB", "subject": "subject1 en_GB"},
        {"title": "title2 en_GB", "subject": "subject2 en_GB"},
        {"title": "title3 en_GB", "subject": "subject3 en_GB"}
    ]
}
```

I've tried angular-translate - https://angular-translate.github.io/ - but it doesn't support arrays. The workaround is to return a string, separated by a delimiter, and then call split() on that string. However, it doesn't support returning JSON objects at all

Currently I'm examining ng-i18next - https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next - an angular module that uses the i18next library, and it's pretty close to what I need.

String arrays are delimited by newline characters - "\n" - so I've split on that character to iterate through an array, but I'm still having the same problem with JSON objects arrays. I can display specific indexes in the array with an index - e.g. objects.0.title, but I can't iterate using ng-repeat.

I've set up a plunker here that demonstrates this - http://plnkr.co/gTuHDZRK0j2fJkw5PBsG
Can anyone suggest a way to iterate through the objects in the "objects" array?

Comment: Map your data to fit the directive that best suits your needs...rather than looking for a directive to fit your data. Doesn't take much to iterate through your arrays to turn them into object that would fit the translate directive. Using object would make it faster to get each translation than array structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correctly in part. I needed fix some bugs to compile the code.

The first problem is on $translate on your controller.
See the code to translate your example correctly:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  var keys = ["one", "two", "three"];
  $scope.objects = []
  angular.forEach(keys, function(value, key) {
    var object = {};
    $translate("objects." + value + ".title").then(function(translation) {
       object.title = translation;
    });
    $translate("objects." + value + ".subject").then(function(translation) {
       object.subject = translation;
    });
    this.push(object);
 }, $scope.objects);
});
```

And in my app.js i configured the $translateProvider just like this:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
prefix: '/languages/',
suffix: '.json'
});
var language = navigator.language.split('-')[0]; //some bugs here
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(language);
```

I have tried with different locale json and works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using angular-translate with a similar solution to the "Load Static Files" demo in the codebase - https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/demo/ex7_load_static_files.htm

I converted the objects array converted to

```
{
  "key": "value en_GB",
    "headings": ["header1 en_GB", "header2 en_GB", "header3 en_GB"],
    "objects": {
        "one": {"title": "title1 en_GB", "subject": "subject1 en_GB"},
        "two": {"title": "title2 en_GB", "subject": "subject2 en_GB"},
        "three": {"title": "title3 en_GB", "subject": "subject3 en_GB"}
    }
}
```

In the controller I've added the keys to an array, and the assigned their translations to an array in $scope, which I can iterate through using ng-repeat in the partial HTML file

```
var keys = ["one", "two", "three"];
$scope.objects = []
angular.forEach(keys, function(value, key) {
    var object = {};
    $translate("objects." + key + ".title").then(function(translation) {
         object.title = translation;
    }
    $translate("objects." + key + ".subject").then(function(translation) {
         object.subject = translation;
    }
    this.push(object);
}, $scope.objects);


<div ng-repeat="object in objects">{{object.title}} {{object.subject}}</div>
```

The downside of this is that any new JSON objects I add to the "objects" array isn't picked up automatically, its attribute name has to be added to the "keys" array to display it on screen.